# Find and replace in Tortoise SVN 1.6.11 repository

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I would like to know the way out to Find and replace specific text/string in html files of an entire repository (which has more than 100 projects/folders) with commit remarks. I have a  basic knowledge of scripting. Also I am using windows 2003 server with VisualSVN Server.

Comment: do you want to replace text in commit logs or in your work area ?

Comment: In my work area (specific code in my html file).

Comment: What do you mean by "with commit remarks"? Do you want to modify only files that have specific text in their latest commit log message or what?

Answer (score 1):

Your modification should be made checking out your repository into a working folder, performing your alterations and commiting.

Changes in versioned files **never** should be made directly in the server.